# Dynamically created <input> is not posting data

Tags: php, html

```
<form  action="test_test.php" name="sdfs" method="post">
<table>
        <?php 
        $rows = "3";
        for ($c=1;$c<=$rows;$c++)
        {?>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="chk[]" id="<?php echo 'chk'.$c?>" value="<?php echo $c ?>"/></td>
<td><label><?php echo 'abc'.$c?></label> 
<input placeholder="aaa" name="<?php echo 'abc'.$c?>" id="<?php echo 'mycol'.$c?>" /></td>
<td><label><?php echo 'mycol'.$c?></label> 
<?php echo '<input name=';
echo 'mycol'.$c;
echo 'id=';
echo 'mycol'.$c.' />' ?>
</tr>
<?php echo '<br>'; }?>
        </table>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"  value="Save" />
        </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['chk']))
{       @$arr = $_POST['chk'];
    foreach (@$_POST['chk'] as $ID) {
        @$b = $_POST['mycol'.$ID];
@$c = $_POST['abc'.$ID];
       echo 'value of $b = '.$b. '<br>';
         echo 'value of $c = '.$c. '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to create a table columns based on a given number.
when I try to post data 
[image: code that i am trying is attached]

1. the input created with php loop does not post data.
2. the Input that i create using html posts data.

can someone help me in posting data from the input that is created in php loop.
am new to php.
thanks

Comment: Please post code as text instead using an image.

Comment: could not find place to attach file except image and code is not posting here, what to do?

Comment: To post code just edit your question, copy and paste your code, select it and press the `{}` button, the selected text will be formatted as code (you also have a `?` button with help).

Comment: checkbox don't send data if is unchecked/ I recommend using `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Jpeg image of the code. Yeah, no. Downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to create dynamic input tags is not correct.
Replace

```
<?php echo '<input name=';
echo 'mycol'.$c;
echo 'id=';
echo 'mycol'.$c.' />' ?>
```

With

```
<?php echo '<input name="mycol'.$c.'" id="mycol'.$c.'" />' ?>
```

or

```
<input  name="<?php echo 'mycol'.$c?>" id="<?php echo 'mycol'.$c?>" />
```

Comment: what is wrong with following code  { <?php echo "<input min='0' max='100' type='number' autocomplete='off' size='10' name='assgn1[$i]' value='echo $rowdet[assgn1];' />";?>}